# Android InputStream.read() horribly slow

Tags: java, android, networking, client, inputstream

I'm working on an Android app that needs to communicate with a server (running on my PC) which is also written by me.
The problem is that InputStream.read() takes an eternity, processing 200kb takes something around 30 seconds. Maybe the garbage collection is involved somehow, during my loop it gets called from time to time but the listed delays are only 2 or 3 millisecods and all in all maybe 20ms so I don't think that's the problem.

My code:

```
client = new Socket("192.168.1.1", 1235);
client.setTcpNoDelay(true);
client.setReceiveBufferSize(1048576);
InputStream is = client.getInputStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];
int i = 0;
int length = -1;

while (true)
{
    int b = is.read();
    if (b == -1)
    {
        success = false;
        break;
    }
    buffer[i] = (byte) b;

    if (i == length)
        break;

    if (i == 3)
    {
        length = buffer[0] | buffer[1] << 8 | buffer[2] << 16 | buffer[3] << 24;
    }

    i++;
}
```

I'm not really experienced in Java and a total beginner in Android programming so I have no idea why it's that damn slow.

Comment: Suggestion: if you want to make a server-client application in Android, I strongly suggest you check some [middleware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middleware) that will do the communication for you, e.g. [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you reading each byte individually? It looks like you really want to read the first 3 bytes and figure out your length and then read that block.

IE:

```
final byte[] lengthBuffer = new byte[3];

int b = is.read(lengthBuffer);

// make sure b was 3 and do your length calculation

final byte buffer = new byte[length];

b = is.read(buffer);

// check b and then you have your bytes
```

Then you can at least get the optimizations that Inputstream can provide for reading blocks of data rather than one byte at a time. And you are not allocating that mega array like you currently have.

Comment: Ok, that's faster, a lot faster, even too fast :/
Now it's done before all data is there...

BTW: I understand that doing 200k iterations isn't as fast as something optimized, but 30 seconds is hilarious, this should still take just milliseconds, .read() must be implemented really inefficiently

Comment: Ok, I just loop over read till length is reached, still a thousand times faster than reading each byte

Comment: @Hidden Read isn't written inefficiently-  its accessing hardware.  By making lots of small reads to the stream you make lots of small reads from the hardware buffers.  That takes time-  you're no longer going at clock speed, you're limited by the bus timings and latencies.  When doing anything with network, storage, etc you have to realize that eventually you hit physical components and need to write to how they work.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading 1 byte at a time.  That's incredibly inefficient.  YOu want to read a large number of bytes at once-  as much as possible.  That's the reason your app is slow.